# Remove an entry from a view

Tags: event-handling, view, cirqus

I wanna know if there is any way to remove an entry from a view.

Ex: You have User Aggregate Root which contains Active property

When the UserCreated event is emitted, the User Active property is set to true
and ActiveUserView is susbcribed to it, so the User appears in the view.

Now UserInactive is emitted for the same aggregate root Id, the InactiveUsersView is subscribed to it but this AG stills in the ActiveUsersView, how can I remove it? or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: I know that I can do a workaround and delete it manually using the aggregate root Id but isn't a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly - but I'll take a stab at it anyway :)

So - my understanding is that you have an aggregate root that emits `UserCreated` and `UserInactive`, and you want to maintain two views: `ActiveUsersView` and `InactiveUsersView`, each containing a view instance for each active and inactive user, respectively.

As there is currently no way to delete a view instance with Cirqus(*), I suggest you change your view to be a `UserActivityStatusView` insted, just flicking a bool on each event - something like this:

```
public class UserActivityStatusView : 
    IViewInstance<InstancePerAggregateRootLocator>,
    ISubscribeTo<UserCreated>,
    ISubscribeTo<UserInactive>
{
    //...

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public void Handle(IViewContext c, UserCreated e) {
        Active = true;
    }

    public void Handle(IViewContext c, UserInactive e) {
        Active = false;
    }
}
```

and then, in your application, you just make sure to query the view with the right criteria.

Does that make sense?

(PS: I apologize for the late answer to your question :))

(* I actually intented to allow for calling `viewContext.MarkForDeletion()`, but it turned out to be more difficult than I anticipated... and I haven't needed it that much, I've always been able to come up with equally good alternative ways of modeling my views)